# Stata using if statements

Tags: stata

I need to check a set of variables and replace a value. For example consider I have three variables `a, b, c`. I need to create a variable `z = 1` if `c` or `b` or `a == 1`.

In other words I need to create an if loop that checks `c` first to see whether `c` is 1; if not I want to check whether `b` is 1; if not whether `a` is 1. And if `c` is 1 then the loop has to stop or if  `b` is 1 it needs to stop from checking `a`.

My code is

```
gen z=. 
foreach var in c b a{
if `var'=1 & z!=. {
replace z=1
}
else
z=.
}
}
```

This code fails to do what I require and I cannot wrap my head around it. I understand I could use a command like this

```
replace z=1 if (a==1|b==1|c==1)
```

but to my understanding this code checks the condition

```
(a==1|b==1|c==1)
```

simultaneously. I require the loop to check each variable `a` `b` `c` step by step.

Comment: Your two previous questions appear to be still open. Please acknowledge an answer or reply to comments.

Comment: What difference does it make the order in which the checked variables are equal to 1? You always put a 1 in `z`.

Answer (score 1):

This is confused or confusing on several levels.

(0) There appears to be buried inside this a problem depending on when `1` first occurs in the dataset. If so, you need to spell that out much more clearly.

(1) You start by saying that you want a new value 1 if any of `a`, `b` or `c` is 1. For that, correct code could be (as you end)

```
replace z = 1 if a == 1 | b == 1 | c == 1
```

or alternatively

```
replace z = 1 if inlist(1, a, b, c)
```

But then you deny that is what you want and talk about a loop. But no loop is required to solve the problem you posed.

(2) The longer code segment you say you used contains illegal statements and could not possibly run. It also (almost certainly) confuses the `if` command you do not want and the `if` qualifier you may want. See [this FAQ for explanation](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/index.html) and [and now this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X231175349).